# Get property values from objects, do calculation, then map in the front end in Angular

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable

I am using Angular 15. I want to get the property values from an array of objects, use the values to do calculation and then map them in the frontend. I had tried 3 different ways, I still can't get what I want but I think I am very close.
The only difference between these 3 methods is, the .subscribe at the end of the codes. Please give me a hit of what to do.

```
export class LeftPanelComponent implements OnInit
  objects: Objects[] = [];
  density: Array<Number>=[];
```

Method 1:

```
getObjects(): void {
    this.restService.getObjects()
    .subscribe((objects: any) => {
      this.objects = objects;
      
      const promise$ = from(objects);
      
      promise$
        .pipe(map((obj:any) => ((obj.mass)/(obj.height * obj.length * obj.width))))
        .subscribe((value) => console.log(`Emitted Values: `, value));

        
 }));
```

Outcome 1:

```
Emitted Values:  253.96825396825395
Emitted Values:  4.444444444444445
Emitted Values:  666.6666666666665
Emitted Values:  200
Emitted Values:  166.66666666666669
Emitted Values:  1666.6666666666667
```

It maps all the values in the console, so I am trying to map those numbers in the frontend.

Method 2:

```
getObjects(): void {
    this.restService.getObjects()
    .subscribe((objects: any) => {
      this.objects = objects;
      
      const promise$ = from(objects);
      
      promise$
        .pipe(map((obj:any) => ((obj.mass)/(obj.height * obj.length * obj.width))))
        .subscribe((value:any) => { this.density = value });
});
```

Outcome 2:

```
Name    Density
Van     1666.6666666666667
Pine tree       1666.6666666666667
Snake       1666.6666666666667
Giraffe     1666.6666666666667
Sheet of paper      1666.6666666666667
Television      1666.6666666666667
```

The table in the frontend only showing the value of the last density item.

Method 3:

```
getObjects(): void {
    this.restService.getObjects()
    .subscribe((objects: any) => {
      this.objects = objects;
      

      
      const promise$ = from(objects);

      promise$
        .pipe(map((obj:any) => ((obj.mass)/(obj.height * obj.length * obj.width))))
        .subscribe(((value:any) => {
          for(let i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
            this.density[i] = value;
          }
}));
```

Outcome 3:
It doesn't do anything in the frontend.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Having subscribe in a subcribe is usually wrong. you should use `mergeMap`, `concatMap`, or `switchMap` in those cases. And when you feel the need to set every type to `any` you are probably on a very wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine for you:

```
   getObjects(): void {
        this.restService
          .getObjects()
          .pipe(
            map((objects) => {
              this.objects = objects;
              return objects.map(
                (obj) => obj.mass / (obj.height * obj.length * obj.width)
              );
            })
          ) 
          .subscribe((values) =>  this.density = value);
      }
```

NB: Avoid nested subscriptions

Comment: It becomes showing the whole array of density instead of just the density for the specific object.

Comment: You can use the index in *ngFor to get the the same item of the object in density array.
But it would be better if you create a Interface {objects:Object, density:number},
Then you will have to loop & map only this array, without having to create two arrays.

Comment: I had tried the <div *ngFor="let density of density; index as i" [attr.data-index]="i">, but the two arrays are still not match.

Answer (score 0):

make your data structure like this

```
datas: Array<{name:string, density:number}>;
```

Create two function

```js
const calculateDensity = (obj) => obj.mass / (obj.height * obj.length * obj.width);

const dataFactory = (objects) => objects.map((obj) => {
  return {name: obj.name, density: calculateDensity(obj)};
});
```

**Angular** : use [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

ts:

```
datas$ = this.restService.getObjects().pipe(map(dataFactory));
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of datas$ | async">
// something like {{ data.name }} - {{ data.density }}
</div>
```